# using JSON_SEARCH to match integer in json data

Tags: mysql, json

I have some json data in video_status_ids in mysql, I am trying to retrieve all records having 3

```
MySql version: 5.7.23
```

Demo records

```
[3, 6, 9]

[7, 3, 10]
```

Query

```
SELECT * FROM `videos` WHERE JSON_SEARCH(video_status_ids, "one", 3);
```

Resulting 0 records

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you would be better off with JSON_CONTAINS

```
SQL > select * from zz where json_contains(doc,'3');
+-----+------------+
| _id | doc        |
+-----+------------+
|   1 | [3, 6, 9]  |
|   2 | [7, 3, 10] |
+-----+------------+
2 rows in set (0.0007 sec)
```

And lets make sure that that it acts correctly on values we do not have

```
SQL > select * from zz where json_contains(doc,'2');
Empty set (0.0006 sec)
```